# run db script from docker container mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, shell

I want to run db set up script from docker container and successfully able to run commands but I need to put all commands in setup.sh into one .sql file and run the same.

Can anyone help and advise on how it can be achieved, when I add create database in dbScript.sql it fails whereas running it separately with mysql command lines works.

setUp.sh

```
#!bin/bash
mysql -u root -p -e "drop database IF EXISTS order_db"
mysql -u root -p -e "create database order_db"
mysql -u root -p order_db < dbScript.sql
```

db.sql

```
USE order_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `order`;

CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

docker container command

```
#!bin/bash
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it ordermanagementsystem_db_1 bash ./setUp.sh
```

Comment: What is the failure when it's run as SQL script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as below:

dbScript.sql

```
drop database IF EXISTS order_db
create database order_db;
USE order_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `order`;

CREATE TABLE `order` (
`id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

docker container command

```
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -i ordermanagementsystem_db_1 mysql -u root -p -e "source dbScript.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

why as a shell script?
you can set up that in your docker-compose.yml file

E.g.:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    web:
      (...)
    database:
      volumes:
        - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro
```

then, you create an *init.sql* file (or whatever any other name) in the defined path. From the example ./mysql/init/init.sql

If you want to have more than one SQL file, they should have a proper name in order to be run in the sequence you wish. So for example do something like this: *01-init.sql*  *02-inserts.sql*  and they will be run in that order ;-)